# How can spaces be removed in HTML output?

Tags: html, css

Here's my HTML code in a markdown editor:

```
<div>

This is some text

<emb>Reference:<emb>
    <ol>
        <li><i>Reference link #1</i></li>
        <li><i>Reference link #2</i></li>
    </ol>
</div>

This is some text.

<style>
  emb {
       font-weight: 500;
       background: transparent;
       font-size: 18px
    }
</style>
```

It produces result as below:

[image]

What causes this space?

Comment: how are you getting output from <emb> tag ? is that for <embed> ?

Comment: what is this `emb` tag?

Comment: probably the `ol` has `margin`. Reset it via CSS.

Comment: `<emb>` is defined in `<style>` in code above.

Comment: Turns out it was margin of 'Reference' text. Strange. So, this worked: `<p style="margin-bottom:0"><emb>Reference:</emb></p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margins of elements. You can use CSS to remove them like this:

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 0;"> <emb> Reference: </emb> </p>
```

and on ol

```
<ol style="margin-top: 0;">
```

I had to remove both margins on `<p>` and on `<ol>` to remove the space
You can also use inspect element on browsers to see the answer.

Comment: Doesn't it change margin for every `ol`?

Comment: Somehow it didn't work as expected. I put the code `<style>` but no change.

Comment: Yes, setting the CSS like that would change margins of every `ol` otherwise you could just make a class eg. `.ol-no-margin` or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: Sorry to hear my solution did not work, I've used inspect element on the provided HTML code and it displayed that ol had a margin. I use firefox so maybe it's different on your browser.

Comment: I used firefox too. It showed I had margin on 'Reference` text instead. Note, I used markdown editor. So, maybe that is why.

Comment: Maybe your markdown editor automatically put `Reference` text in paragraph. Could be the reason why I couldn't see margins on it. But anyways glad you managed to fix it.

Comment: I think so. This was actual HTML from markdown I just extracted: https://bpa.st/3TLA Can you see the problem better now?

Comment: Yes now I can see it clearly, every element has a margin there. I'm using VSCode which doesn't automatically add <p></p> on elements without specification.

Comment: You can edit your answer to correct it then I'll accept it.